# Communication between processing and Python?

Tags: python, server, client, processing

I am writing a program in processing and am trying to find away to get it to communicate with an enviro pHAT, which uses a python library. How can I create a local server on processing which I can connect to a client in python?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Processing's Network library:
https://processing.org/reference/libraries/net/index.html

Here's an example of setting up a server:
https://processing.org/reference/libraries/net/Server.html